# Backup 2 remote servers at different time

Tags: rsnapshot

I have 2 remote servers, which I backup from my backup server using rsnapshot.

My config section for backup is something like this:

```
backup  root@example1.com:/var/db/dump/ example1.com/
backup  root@example2.com:/var/db/dump/ example2.com/
```

Cronjob is nearly such:

```
0 3 * * *    /usr/bin/rsnapshot daily
```

But in such case 2 servers will be backuped one by one in 3 AM. I would like to backup one server in 3 AM and second in 10 AM. What changes should I make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a second config file for the second server (copy and edit) and then change your cronjob like this:

```
0  3 * * *    /usr/bin/rsnapshot -c /path/to/config_server1.cfg daily 
0 10 * * *    /usr/bin/rsnapshot -c /path/to/config_server2.cfg daily
```